# Slow Pandas query to get differene between rows based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a big dataframe as input that looks like this:

```
index type price
3000   C    300
3000   P    500
3500   C    300
3500   P    400
4500   P    100
```

I would like to get the index value where for the same index but different type (C and P), the price difference is the smallest.

Right now I do the following but it takes a couple of seconds:

```py
k_c = np.unique(df.index[(df['type'] == 'C')])
k_p = np.unique(df.index[(df['type'] == 'P')])

common_k = np.intersect1d(k_c, k_p)

diff = [np.abs(df['price'][(df['type'] == 'C') & (df.index == k)].values[0] -
               df['price'][(df['type'] == 'P') & (df.index == k)].values[0]) for k in common_k]

min_index = common_k[np.argmin(diff)]
```

Is there a way to make this faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot) + [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html#pandas-dataframe-diff) on axis=1, then [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html#pandas-series-idxmin):

```
min_index = (
    df.reset_index()
        .pivot(index='index', columns='type', values='price')
        .dropna()
        .diff(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].abs().idxmin()
)
```

`min_index`:

```
3500
```

*Note `pivot` only works if there are no duplicate 'C' or 'P' values in the same index.

---

[`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot) to get values side by side per index:

```
df.reset_index().pivot(index='index', columns='type', values='price')
```

```
type       C      P
index              
3000   300.0  500.0
3500   300.0  400.0
4500     NaN  100.0
```

[`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas-dataframe-dropna) to get rid of rows that don't have both values:

```
type       C      P
index              
3000   300.0  500.0
3500   300.0  400.0
```

[`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html#pandas-dataframe-diff) on axis 1:

```
type    C      P
index           
3000  NaN  200.0
3500  NaN  100.0
```

[`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas-dataframe-iloc) to get the last column (where the diff accumulated).

```
index
3000    200.0
3500    100.0
Name: P, dtype: float64
```

[`abs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html#pandas-series-abs) to get the absolute numeric value of each element.

[`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html#pandas-series-idxmin) to get index of the min value:

```
3500
```

Comment: Amazing answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: another quick help, how would you do if you need to have a more complex calculation, like this one:  
np.array([k + df['price'].values[(df['type'] == 'C') & (df.index == k)] / 0.99999
                 - df['price'].values[(df['type'] == 'P') & (df.index == k)] / 0.9999
                 for k in common_k])

Comment: Code in comments is hard to parse. I'd suggest you create a _new_ question (so as to not invalidate the answers already here for this one) which outlines the new computation, provides a sample frame to test with, as well as, expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You may check with `groupby`

```
inxout = df.sort_values('price').groupby('type')['price'].diff().idxmin()
2
```